# App detailed-Http Logs in Azure App Service for Linux

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

I hosted a web API on azure app service using a docker image (linux) And for production purpose I need all http requests to be logged. I tried " Diagnostic settings (preview)" and I selected "Archive to a storage account" , But when I checked my logs I found all http request except request & response body and header.

So, is there a way to log this details for debugging purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a container in a web app, then all the web app monitoring is doing is extracting the container logs and storing them. You need to configure logging in whatever container you are running to output the data you want to log, to the container log.